# Logstash with Multiple Inputs and Outputs

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I'm able to get Logstash to parse data from a variety of sources and send it to Elasticsearch, but I'm not having much luck working with file inputs.

The directory `/data` contains a variety of input files starting with a name, like `a`, followed by a date. Today, the directory may contain `a_20170611.csv` and `a_20170612.csv`, which have not yet been parsed. Each day a new file `a` is added. So, tomorrow `a_20170613.csv` will be added, and the original files remain (at least for a short period of time until they're purged).

When I start Logstash for the first time, I'd like Logstash to grab the files that are already there and send the data to Elasticsearch. Then, when new files are available each day, I'd like Logstash to grab the new file and send the data to Elasticsearch. Older files will never contain new data, so Logstash should ignore them once they've been handled.

Here is my **logstash-pipeline.conf**:

```
input {
  file { path => "/data/a_*.csv"
         delimiter => "|" 
         type => "a"  } 

  file { path => "/data/b_*.csv"
        delimiter => "|" 
        type => "b" } 

  file { path => "/data/c_*.csv" 
         delimiter => "|" 
         type => "c" } 

  file { path => "/data/d_*.csv" 
        delimiter => "|" 
        type => "d" } 
        }

output {
  if [type] == "a" {
      elasticsearch { hosts => ["ip:port"]
                      index => "logstash-a-%{+YYYYMMDD}" }
                            }
  if [type] == "b" {
      elasticsearch { hosts => ["ip:port"]
                      index => "logstash-b-%{+YYYYMMDD}" }
                      }

  if [type] == "c" {
      elasticsearch { hosts => ["ip:port"]
                      index => "logstash-c-%{+YYYYMMDD}" }
                      }
  if [type] == "d" {
      elasticsearch { hosts => ["ip:port"]
                      index => "logstash-d-%{+YYYYMMDD}" }
                    }                 
    }
```

Comment: I can't see anything obviously wrong with this. What way is it misbehaving?

Comment: It wasn't doing anything. The logs provided 0 insight. I added start_position => "beginning" to the input pipeline and removed .sincedb_* from /var/lib/logstash/plugins/inputs/file and it worked.

Comment: `start_position => "beginning"` is what you needed here, yes. I wasn't sure if you were looking to index everything already present when logstash runs, everything that comes in while logstash runs, or both.